# How to instruct phantomjs to avoid timeout when using binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, pry, poltergeist

at some point, I don't know if you guys call it REPL-driven development or something, but I find myself inspecting the contents of my runtime by inserting a `binding.pry` call in some test. This works pretty well, except when I'm running Cucumber tests because I've chosen `poltergeist` as my `capybara` driver, which uses `phantomjs`. I can get the REPL to launch but after some time it's killed and I get a timeout error from `phantomjs`, I wonder whether there's a way to fix this, even if it includes switching to `pry-remote` or similar. This probably had been asked before but I just couldn't find an answer. Clues?

Comment: Have you tried `pry-remote` yet? It looks like this would help, since pry would run in a separate process.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It happens to me, too.

Answer (score 2):

i put this in my spec_helper so i could set the timeout

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {timeout: 600, js_errors: false} )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Within pry you should be able to do:

```
page.driver.timeout = 10000
```

or

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.timeout = 10000
```

This should get passed all the way down to the socket handling code and I think it will do the job, though I haven't tried it...